# iPhone Date format from Chinese to English

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate

From my locale i am getting Chinese date in iPhone, i need to convert that into English using NSDateFormatter. I have tried using the code below, but in the response, i am getting Chinese words also.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh-Hans"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy年MM月dd日'"];
NSDate *dateTmp  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014年3月14日"]; // getting date from string with english locale
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTmp]; // getting string from date with spanish locale
NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

This is the output it is showing 2014年3月14日, however i don't need Chinese words in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also give the date formate of english as below

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh-Hans"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy年MM月dd日'"];
NSDate *dateTmp  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014年3月14日"]; // getting date from string with english locale
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTmp]; // getting string from date with spanish locale

NSLog(@"Your OUTPUT IS : %@",strDate);
```

**Your OUTPUT IS : 2014-03-14**

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh-Hans"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy年MM月dd日'"];
    NSDate *dateTmp  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014年3月14日"]; // getting date from string with english locale

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd'"];
    [dateFormatter2 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:dateTmp]; // getting string from date with spanish locale
    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next method to get localized format based on template:

```
NSString *neededFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMMM dd, yyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```